# Как присвоить переменной сообщение пользователя telebot python

Tags: python, telebot

Делаю телеграм бота, и не могу понять как мне присвоить переменной сообщение отправленное пользователем

И как подобное сделать для нескольких переменных? То есть каждое сообщение пользователя будет заносится в отдельную переменную

Answer (score 3):

Использовал пример [эхо-бота](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/87bce0bce149bc6b3aa67f1252a3115273d94c3f/examples/echo_bot.py)

В переменной `text` будет находиться сообщение, отправленное пользователем:

```
import telebot

API_TOKEN = '<api_token>'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    text = message.text
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    bot.reply_to(message, text)


bot.polling()
```

---

> А как подобное сделать для нескольких переменных? То есть каждое
> сообщение пользователя будет заносится в отдельную переменную

Сделать список или словарь, куда складывать сообщения. Если использовать словарь, тогда удобно в него по ключу складывать id пользователя, а в значение список сообщений. Если список, то, например, просто в список сообщения

```
from collections import defaultdict
import telebot

API_TOKEN = '<api_token>'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)

user_by_messages = defaultdict(list)
messages = []

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    text = message.text
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    
    user_by_messages[user_id].append(text)
    messages.append(text)
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    bot.reply_to(message, text)


bot.polling()
```

---

#### Но, если куда-то сохранять данные, то лучше всего в базу данных.

Покажу пример с `sqlite3`. В рабочей папке скрипта появится файл `db.sqlite`. *В таблице всего 2 поля, но скорее всего понадобится больше полей, например дату и время, а может быть id чата*

```
import sqlite3
import telebot


API_TOKEN = '<api_token>'
DB_FILE_NAME = 'db.sqlite'


def create_connect():
    return sqlite3.connect(DB_FILE_NAME)


def init_db():
    # Создание базы и таблицы
    with create_connect() as connect:
        connect.execute('''
            CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Message (
                id      INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY,
                user_id INTEGER  NOT NULL,
                text    TEXT  NOT NULL
            );
        ''')

        connect.commit()


def add_message(user_id, message):
    with create_connect() as connect:
        connect.execute(
            'INSERT INTO Message (user_id, text) VALUES (?, ?)', (user_id, message)
        )
        connect.commit()


init_db()


bot = telebot.TeleBot(API_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def echo_message(message):
    text = message.text
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    
    add_message(user_id, text)
    # ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    
    bot.reply_to(message, text)


bot.polling()
```

Comment: А как подобное сделать для нескольких переменных? То есть каждое сообщение пользователя будет заносится в отдельную переменную

Comment: Создаете список вне функции, чтобы он был глобальный, а лучше сохраняете в базу данных. Покажу пример

Comment: @kyron, думаю, я в ответе разъяснил все и даже больше :) Пожалуйста, не забудьте [проголосовать и принять мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) ;)